# Can you in some way design a "sketch" illustration theme for Google Maps?

Tags: illustration, maps, sketching

Is there any way to make Google Maps like this?

[image]

[This](https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-the-pencil-map-style-f8c57dae0e88) is promising, but not for Google Maps. [This](https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-turn-a-map-into-an-artistic-line-drawing/) *doesn't* look promising :)

Comment: What do you mean, automatically? using a software - which one? Or are you planning to customize google maps itself for user interaction? I'm affraid your question is a bit too vague, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps offers a *very* extensive API for style customisation. You can customise almost any element. This is done through a Javascript API: the styles are saved in a JSON structure and then applied when the map is loaded in your website. You can find the full documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en).

But Google also offers a Wizard which lets you control almost all of the customisations through an interactive UI. You can find said wizard [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com). Be aware that this wizard does *not* offer all customisation options. For example, you [can set a custom font for labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157340/2895454), yet there is no such option in the wizard.

Things like the boat, dragons, a compass and other 'old-timey' map features can be done through [custom overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays). However, this is pretty advanced, so I'd suggest to try getting a feel for the API's simpler functions first.

How I would go about this:

1. Start customising through the wizard and try to get as close as I can.
2. Load the map in a webpage (you can use a free online service like Codepen too)
3. Customise styling further through the JSON options until I'm as close as possible
4. Add custom SVG elements

Comment: Can my illustration example be done though? I know they offer customization, but THIS much customization? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: I don't know. For that I'd have to start experimenting, but then I'd be doing your job. I'm pretty sure the 3D skew effect is impossible, unless you start using CSS transforms on the whole map after you've styled it.

Comment: No need for 3D skew effect, just b+w sketch effect.

Comment: I'm talking like [this](https://github.com/puzzleboks/parchment_mapbox) but for Google Maps.